What's the correct reply to “nice to meet you”?
I’ve learnt all my life replying to “nice to meet you” as “me too” or likewise and so on. But maybe I am learning wrong or whatever, I have seen people replying in American soaps and movies as “you too” as probably shorthand for “nice to meet you too" (correct me If I am wrong). I understand where this is coming from but I want to know from the Natives. Are both acceptable? Is it just another US/UK thing?

"You too" sounds a bit odd to me (why not "Me too"?), but if you hear it from native speakers, by all means copy it. Personally, I'd probably respond with "Likewise" (or nothing plus a smile / wave / handshake), but people say many different things in this context. You could always go the whole hog in "formal, polite" terms with something like "The pleasure was all mine", but these days that would usually be a somewhat facetious response.

This question is similar to: Saying "very much" right after "Nice to meet you, too". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Both very casual, and both are ok. I would use both depending on where the focus of the matching sentence was. (1) "Nice to meet you." "Me too" [meaning It feels nice to me also to have this meeting.] (2) "Have a great day" "You too" [meaning I wish for you the same good time that you just wished for me.]

"Me too" only sounds right when the other person has said something of themselves, for example "I am pleased to meet you". They have said something about themselves using the pronoun 'I', and you're saying the same is true for yourself with 'me'.
Although "nice to meet you" has a similar meaning, it's really a shortening of "it's nice to meet you" which is a statement about the situation of your meeting, so "me too" as a response isn't strictly correct.
Your answer of "nice to meet you too" is obviously fine, because you're literally saying the same thing back that was just said.
Perhaps the easiest idiomatic answer would be to say: "likewise". This works in response to either of the above possibilities because it essentially means "the same thing you just said".

There is no way that can be called correct in exclusivity of any other; there are rather several "correct" ways, but the criterion, in the end is one that has to do with the "communicated"  impression of satisfaction, pleasure, felt recognition.
You may reply "me too", and it is correct, but your initiative, if  your reply can be thus categorized, has nothing but the touch of a common run reply—not to be mistaken as impolite, or unacceptable, no, not at all, it is not—, and you might very well use it, but do not expect to impart to the person you are meeting the idea that you are charmed/impressed/interested by their person. It will be better, in the way of sounding more appreciative, to repeat "nice to meet you" in a more expressive "nice to meet you, too" (instead of just "me too"), but this formula still has the touch of a perfunctory reply that will communicate nothing special; of course, your body language might  give to this perfunctory utterance a certain warmth that will more than compensate for its plainness. Let's not forget than in any case, body language, to a greater or lesser extent, will be a cue to the  interpretation of your strictly verbal greeting. You can also go one better than the person you are meeting, so to  speak, as there is no matter for competition here, and say "so (very) nice to meet you"; you will then be communicating something special. There are many variants, depending on the person you meet; for instance, in the case of your meeting an important man you might say "((I am) very) honoured to meet you sir/Mr so and so/professor/etc". For people to whom you do not want to confer as much respect, but to whom you are eager to confer your appreciation, you might say "It is a pleasure to meet you", or in a shortened, but less polite way, say simply "pleasure".  In general, it is better not copy a "nice to meet you" that has been extended to you and instead reply with "glad to meet you" or "pleased to meet you", or some other variant, and that will sound less perfunctory.
Not all "correct" formulas have been commented upon in the paragraphs above, but what appear to be important basic ideas have been given about some usual formulas.
(It must be said that the present answer reflects  strictly user LPH's opinions, which still might still be found helpful as they might ring a bell in the reader's mind.)

This sounds to me like an answer that would be appropriate for a 19th century book on manners.

@Xanne Would you tell me then that replying with a simple "me too" is considered fine? I would say it's acceptable; In fact, a  part of my answer coincides with opinions found here.

You should provide references and time frames for your statements.

@Xanne While deciding to write this answer it seemed to me I wouldn't find much that could support my impressions,; this turned out to be not so true as when faced with necessity to show that those impressions were not those of a past century, I happened to find facts that can be used to verify what I said (some of it, at least).
